# WSO2 ESB dependancy on Governance registry

Tags: registry, wso2, soa, wso2-esb

If WSO2 ESB is integrated with remote governance repository and if the governance registry is crashed  does the ESB detects that and don't refresh the cache untill the repository is restored ?

And any one know of the usecase where some one using governance repositor in production in conjunction with ESB ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not use programatic access to the registry API, there is no problem.
The ESB accesses directly to the GREG database.